# How can I Pass two value in spinner one for ID and second for Title

Tags: android, spinner

### How can I Pass two value in spinner one for ID and second for item Title and show only item title in spinner but get also both with onClick listener.

**I want to create spinner for app that will show me title but i also need that when i click on any item it show me ID and Title.**

**so please tell me how can i set ID and Title With Array List and get access it on click event.**

**This is my code that show me item and it's position but i want also custom ID that i put with item title.**

```
  ArrayList<String> items=new ArrayList<>();
     SpinnerDialog spinnerDialog;
     ImageView imageView;
    
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_menu);
    

// Searching With Spinner[START]

            initItems();
            spinnerDialog =new SpinnerDialog(DrawerMenu.this,items,"Select Item");
    
            spinnerDialog.bindOnSpinerListener(new OnSpinerItemClick() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(String item, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(DrawerMenu.this,"Selected: "+item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            
            imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.search_Quali); 
            
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();
                }
            });
    
        }
    
        private void initItems() {
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            {
                items.add("Item"+(i+1));
               
            }
        }
    
        // Searching With Spinner[END]
    
    }
```

Comment: there is no `Spinner` in your code - only some unknown `SpinnerDialog`

Comment: i have used compile 'com.github.MdFarhanRaja:SearchableSpinner:1.9'
library so spinner automatically show.

https://github.com/MdFarhanRaja/SearchableSpinner

Comment: so ask the [author](https://github.com/MdFarhanRaja) of that library

Comment: ok i will asking

Comment: Seeing as that code is open source, you may want to take a look at it. Perhaps you can then fork the code and modify it appropriately and share this back via GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Data> items=new ArrayList<>();
    SpinnerDialog spinnerDialog;
    ImageView imageView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_menu);


// Searching With Spinner[START]

        initItems();
        spinnerDialog =new SpinnerDialog(DrawerMenu.this,items,"Select Item");

        spinnerDialog.bindOnSpinerListener(new OnSpinerItemClick() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Data item, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(DrawerMenu.this,"Selected: "+item.getId()+" "+item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.search_Quali);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void initItems() {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            items.add(new Data(101+i+"","Item"+(i+1)));

        }
    }


    class Data {

        String Id,title;

        Data(String id,String title)
        {
            this.title=title;
            this.Id=id;

    }

        public String getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }


        // Searching With Spinner[END]

}
```